# how to join tables and left joins in a better way PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have formulated this query

```
select *, (cameras_owned + camera_shares) total_cameras 
from ( select *, 
              (select count(cr.id) 
               from cloud_recordings cr 
               left join cameras c on c.owner_id=u.id 
               where c.id=cr.camera_id 
               and cr.status <>'off' 
               and cr.storage_duration <> 1),
              (select count(*) 
               from cameras cc 
               left join users uuu on cc.owner_id=uuu.id 
               where uuu.id=u.id) cameras_owned,
              (select count(*) 
               from camera_shares cs 
               left join users uuuu on cs.user_id=uuuu.id 
               where uuuu.id = u.id) camera_shares,
              (select count(*) 
               from snapmails sm 
               left join users suser on sm.user_id=suser.id 
               where suser.id = u.id) snapmail_count,
              (select name 
               from countries ct 
               left join users uuuuu on ct.id=uuuuu.country_id 
               where uuuuu.id=u.id) country,
              (select name 
               from companies cp 
               left join users uuuuuu on cp.id=uuuuuu.company_id 
               where uuuuuu.id=u.id) company_name,
              (select count(cs1.id) 
               from camera_shares cs1 
               where cs1.user_id=u.id 
                 and cs1.camera_id = 279) share_id
       from users u 
       where 1=1 
       order by created_at desc ) t
```

and its working all fine, my question is is there any better way of doing it?

Right now, there are 2 sorts and 2 where clauses

Such as

these all sorts values

```
["payment_method", "username", "name", "email", "api_id", "api_key", "cameras_owned", "camera_shares", "snapmail_count", "country", "company_name", "created_at", "last_login_at", "referral_url"]
```

work right after `from users u {sorting and order}`

and `total_cameras` work only after `t` part.

Same as I have multiple conditions, all conditions which are `u.` all go in `from users u` but then all other conditions which include

1. total_cameras
2. cameras_owned
3. camera_shares
4. share_id
5. company_name

these all above goes after `t` part,

I am looking for a solution where is it possible to write this query in such way that I can put sorting and all condition in one place instead of 2 2 different places?

Answer (score 0):

I have formatted your query in the question. Now you can freely see that ALL your `LEFT JOIN`s are in reality `INNER JOIN`s due to null-rejecting conditions in the `WHERE` clause by a field from joined table.

> Right now, there are 2 sorts and 2 where clauses

*2 where clauses*

`COUNT(*) .. WHERE (condition)` is equal to `COUNT(CASE WHEN (condition) THEN 1 END)`.

*2 sorts*

I see one sorting only. And, by the way, it is posessed in subquery and, so, it will be ignored - if output seems to be sorted, it is random. - [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the LEFT JOINs to the `users` table in your sub-queries.

For example, this:

```
(select count(*) 
 from cameras cc 
 left join users uuu on cc.owner_id=uuu.id 
 where uuu.id=u.id) cameras_owned
```

can be simplified to

```
(select count(*) 
 from cameras cc 
 where cc.owner_id = u.id) cameras_owned
```

Same for the other `count(*)` subqueries. For readability I would also get the country and company name through a regular join, rather than a sub-query.

So the inner query would be something like this:

```
select *, 
        (select count(cr.id) 
         from cloud_recordings cr 
           join cameras c on c.owner_id = u.id 
         where c.id=cr.camera_id 
         and cr.status <> 'off' 
         and cr.storage_duration <> 1),
        (select count(*) 
         from cameras cc 
         where cc.owner_id = u.id) cameras_owned,
        (select count(*) 
         from camera_shares cs 
         where cs.user_id = u.id) camera_shares,
        (select count(*) 
         from snapmails sm 
         where sm.user_id = u.id) snapmail_count,
        ct.name as country,
        cp.name as company_name,
        (select count(cs1.id) 
         from camera_shares cs1 
         where cs1.user_id=u.id 
           and cs1.camera_id = 279) share_id
from users u 
  left join companies cp on cp.id = u.company_id 
  left join countries ct on ct.id = u.country_id
where 1=1 
order by created_at desc
```

Note that the `order by` in the inner query is not guaranteed to be preserved by the outer query (although very likely it will be). But nevertheless you should always move an `order by` to outermost query (unless you need it e.g. for a `limit`).

Comment: what about `(cameras_owned + camera_shares) total_cameras`

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: as I wrote: that example is only the **inner** query. You still need to wrap it to have access to the column aliases (which I referred to as the **outer** query where you should apply the `order by`)

Comment: I just ran and got this error `ERROR:  ORDER BY "created_at" is ambiguous
LINE 27: order by created_at desc`

Comment: Apparently the other tables also have a `created_at` column, so you have to use the right alias: `u.created_at`

Comment: what If you want to query to camera_owned? `and lower(cp.name) like lower('%Evercam%') and lower(u.email) like lower('%junaid%') and lower(u.firstname || ' ' || u.lastname) like lower('%Jun%') and cameras_owned > 3`
this will never work

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: why shouldn't that work?

Comment: I have no idea, i just query and it didnt work, thats the problem I was trying to describe from the very start.